# How can I make this database better?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am beginner to database design and having a trouble on the database design for groupon website like Groupon.com  and this is my diagram from my idea. I am hoping for some advise on

1. How can I improve this EER diagram?
2. Are there any common mistakes that I should avoid ?
3. Am I on the right track? Or can you propose an alternative design pattern that I have yet to consider?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Sorry for my poor English. Thank you in advance!

[contextdiagram](https://s16.postimg.org/nwwugysv9/context_diagram.jpg) [EER diagram](https://postimg.org/image/3qtci2x7l/)

Comment: See: [Five Simple Database Design Error You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/)

Comment: it does not matter how beautiful and normalized tables for the real world application when your queries works slow. so, it's better to analyse what you want to do with the database before design it. normalize a db and having less of data in it is good, because it helps to fit your db in RAM and provide good performance. But sometimes because of not all parts of a data queried with the same  frequency it is better to avoid normalization. Read docs, try your design, and get your experience, as far as no one tells you a statistic for your data.

Answer (score 0):

As to the database schema, I would:

1. Change it, so that the order has a FK to orderStatus. This way, you
   minimise the number of orderStatus records in your database. This way you have few possible statuses ("In progress", "New", etc..) and your order relates to that . Just like you did with payment. Where is order total?
2. I would make address more atomic. Split it into country, city, street, postal number. It will be easier to process shipment that way.
3. Instead of making a purchasedItem table, I'd create a productOrder one, with FK to product, FK to order and with number of items (Look into Many to Many relations). This way your order can have many different items (You don't need productName aggregated there too).
4. You did a quite nice job with promotions, but in my opinion it would require quite a big help from the program side. You'd have to manually compute your item total and order total.

I hope it helps a little. If you need help, ask in the comment. 
Some reading for you: [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)